# Develop software that doesn't need installation

Tags: c#, .net, installation, desktop-application, usb-drive

I am a software developer and currently I am having requirement to develop such data management software for one retailer that doesn't require installation. Means client want software that should be pre installed in pen drive and while my client access that pen drive from any pc then he must be able to access whole software without any kind of cause or installation.

How could I develop such software? Is it possible to develop such software in .net (I am familiar with it)?

Comment: The client machine should have at least the .Net framework installed..

Comment: And your application should not be dealing with the registry.

Comment: Is it possible in any other language to develop such software? I ask for .Net because I am having 3 years of experience in it. But if you suggest any other language then also it's fine. I don't want to loos this contract and it's accounting kind of software.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the machines that you're working with already have the .NET framework installed that you required, then no problem.  You can just run the .NET code from your pend drive.

However, if you can't guarantee that the .NET framework is already installed, .NET is not going to work in this scenario.  A solution that comes to mind in that scenario is a bare bones Win32 C++ solution.

Comment: Is it possible in any other language to develop such software? I ask for .Net because I am having 3 years of experience in it. But if you suggest any other language then also it's fine. I don't want to loos this contract and it's accounting kind of software.

Comment: The only other one that I can think of (besides Assembly which is relatively unthinkable IMHO) is Visual Basic 6 (VB6).  The runtime is supported up through Windows 8.  There are likely others, but those are the ones that come to mind.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just put the exe (and dll) files onto the pen drive.  You don't need to build an installer.

Comment: Is it possible in any other language to develop such software? I ask for .Net because I am having 3 years of experience in it. But if you suggest any other language then also it's fine. I don't want to loos this contract and it's accounting kind of software.

Comment: if you want to impress you're client, you should use the languages you're familiar with.  If you want to learn something, use languages you're not familiar with.  This is the formula I use to decide what language to use for a project.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem at all, as long as you don't try to use the registry, or any local folders on the PC without expecting problems.

Comment: I assumed that was obvious. I have also assumed that the PC will have a USB drive if they want to use a pen drive...

Comment: the latter is a valid assumption in this case.  The former is not (given what the OP initially provided).

Comment: Is it possible in any other language to develop such software? I ask for .Net because I am having 3 years of experience in it. But if you suggest any other language then also it's fine. I don't want to loos this contract and it's accounting kind of software.

Comment: Any language that doesn't require a dependency on the PC should be fine. Where are you planning to store the data for the program though?

Answer (score 1):

That's not an install.

An install is where you tell the operating system about the software.

.net out of the box is XCopy deploy. ie Build, open File manager click on the exe and it should just work.

So it you copy the build files to a clean machine, pen drive, cd, of just a foklder and it works, then job done.

No permanent registry, no appdata folders, no shortcuts.

Comment: Is it possible in any other language to develop such software? I ask for .Net because I am having 3 years of experience in it. But if you suggest any other language then also it's fine. I don't want to loos this contract and it's accounting kind of software.

Comment: Huh. It is possible in .net. In fact it's the way .net works "out of the box". To do an install, as in see your application in programs and features etc, requires extra work. Just copy the contents of the bin/release folder (or where ever VS builds it to), on to a pen drive and give it a go.

Comment: What if I don't have .Net framework installed in that PC on which I am accessing my pen drive?

Comment: Well that would be a problem! But a completely different one. No .net is can't use .net. Alternative's lots of old ones, depends on what you are comfortable with. If they really have PCs with no .net framework on still, drop them or charge more, lots and lots more.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. For instance, if you develop a software that does require installation, and  you want to ask a co worker to test the app for you, you could go into your debug folder (or release) and give him the `.exe` + eventually the `DLLs`. He will be able to run it without any problem.

Just remember to keep all save files, ressources and dll's in the same folder.

The only thing is, without an installer, you wont have access to all the features an installer has, such as checking for prerequisites, installing prerequisites, inserting keys into the registry etc ... 
You will have to do without these "integrated" functionnalities